# Why do keystrokes in "less"/"more" sometimes require a <ENTER>, when i use a pipe?

Tags: pipe

I love the pipe to feed long text output into `less` (or `more`) to make it more readable. It's only on Ubuntu that i observed a uncommon behavior: Sometimes in less keystrokes are not processed immediately. It's like i have to "confirm" them with `<ENTER>`. For example less opens, text is displayed, i hit `<SPACE>` (nothing happens), i hit `<ENTER>` (page scrolls down now). This is very annoying, as it makes less practically unusable because the  also messes up the terminal output.

It doesn't happen for all piped commands. One example is:

`php --rc PDO | less`

I've never seen this happen on any other Linux distribution.

Answer (score 3):

I've been battling with this problem all afternoon and, after finding this question and reading several manpages, had a bit of a brainwave. It turns out that redirecting STDIN to `/dev/null` acts as a workaround and returns "normal" functionality to `less`:

```
php --rc PDO < /dev/null | less
```

or

```
cat /dev/null | php --rc PDO | less
```

It is, of course, a horrible kludge of a workaround, and I don't have nearly enough knowledge of pipes and stream redirection in Bash to really understand what causes the problem or why this fixes it, but I figured that posting this was better than leaving this question entirely unanswered. Hopefully someone more knowledgeable than myself will be able to shed some light on this - ideally with a more realistic fix.

My only guess is that `php` is receiving STDIN instead of `less` when you type commands into `less`, but I'm baffled as to why this behaviour is only seen in Ubuntu (I have confirmed that `php --rc PDO | less` works fine in Sabayon, CentOS and Debian, while breaking on several different Ubuntu installs, including those updated to 11.10).

Updating to include some relevant search results I've found. Turns out it's a problem with Ubuntu's build of `php-cli`, so it shouldn't affect any other commands.

- [`drush help | less` doesn't work on Ubuntu 10.10+ (video inside) | drupal.org](http://drupal.org/node/877916)
- [Bug #322214 in php5 (Ubuntu): “php (via libedit using_history()) incorrectly opens stdin”](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php5/+bug/322214)

Comment: Signed up here merely to say thank you! I'd been having trouble with `less` misbehaving while receiving data on a pipe; but working fine if I instead dumped the output to a file and then ran `less` on it. Redirecting `STDIN` to `/dev/null` as you said fixed the problem for me and now I can happily pipe again :)